# SuperCollider not audible on headphone

Tags: ide, programming-languages, supercollider

I am just beginning to learn audio programming using supercollider. 
When I play a sound I am able to hear it on speakers but not headphone.

I get the following message on starting server -

> booting 57110
>   localhost
>   JackDriver: client name is 'SuperCollider'
>   SC_AudioDriver: sample rate = 48000.000000, driver's block size = 1024
>   JackDriver: connected  system:capture_1 to SuperCollider:in_1
>   JackDriver: connected  system:capture_2 to SuperCollider:in_2
>   JackDriver: connected  SuperCollider:out_1 to system:playback_1
>   JackDriver: connected  SuperCollider:out_2 to system:playback_2
>   SuperCollider 3 server ready.
>   JackDriver: max output latency 42.7 ms
>   Receiving notification messages from server localhost
>   Shared memory server interface initialized

I went through some forums and they suggested to look for output devices options and set them, I did a -

```
ServerOptions.devices;
```

to look for device list but I got the following error in the post window -

> ERROR: A primitive was not bound. 0 676
>   Instance of Method {    (0x21199c0, gc=01, fmt=00, flg=11, set=04)
>     instance variables [15]
>       raw1 : Float 0.000000   00000000 0080000C
>       raw2 : Float 0.000000   00000300 03020003
>       code : instance of Int8Array (0x2119cc0, size=4, set=2)
>       selectors : nil
>       constants : nil
>       prototypeFrame : instance of Array (0x2119c00, size=3, set=2)
>       context : nil
>       argNames : instance of SymbolArray (0x2119b40, size=3, set=2)
>       varNames : nil
>       sourceCode : nil
>       ownerClass : class Meta_ServerOptions (0x21113c0)
>       name : Symbol 'prListDevices'
>       primitiveName : Symbol '_ListAudioDevices'
>       filenameSymbol : Symbol '/usr/share/SuperCollider/SCClassLibrary/Common/Control/Server.sc'
>       charPos : Integer 4025
>   }
>   ERROR: Primitive 'none' failed.
>   Failed.
>   RECEIVER:
>      nil
>   CALL STACK:
>       MethodError:reportError   0x3601498
>           arg this = 
>       Nil:handleError   0x1f730f8
>           arg this = nil
>           arg error = 
>       Thread:handleError   0x35fcfd8
>           arg this = 
>           arg error = 
>       Object:throw   0x3980c58
>           arg this = 
>       Object:primitiveFailed   0x33395a8
>           arg this = nil
>       Interpreter:interpretPrintCmdLine   0x3d061e8
>           arg this = 
>           var res = nil
>           var func = 
>           var code = "ServerOptions.devices;"
>           var doc = nil
>           var ideClass = 
>       Process:interpretPrintCmdLine   0x3443c08
>           arg this = 
>   ^^ The preceding error dump is for ERROR: Primitive 'none' failed.
>   Failed.
>   RECEIVER: nil
>   booting 57110
>   localhost
>   JackDriver: client name is 'SuperCollider'
>   SC_AudioDriver: sample rate = 48000.000000, driver's block size = 1024
>   JackDriver: connected  system:capture_1 to SuperCollider:in_1
>   JackDriver: connected  system:capture_2 to SuperCollider:in_2
>   JackDriver: connected  SuperCollider:out_1 to system:playback_1
>   JackDriver: connected  SuperCollider:out_2 to system:playback_2
>   SuperCollider 3 server ready.
>   JackDriver: max output latency 42.7 ms
>   Receiving notification messages from server localhost
>   Shared memory server interface initialized
>   ERROR: A primitive was not bound. 0 676
>   Instance of Method {    (0x21199c0, gc=01, fmt=00, flg=11, set=04)
>     instance variables [15]
>       raw1 : Float 0.000000   00000000 0080000C
>       raw2 : Float 0.000000   00000300 03020003
>       code : instance of Int8Array (0x2119cc0, size=4, set=2)
>       selectors : nil
>       constants : nil
>       prototypeFrame : instance of Array (0x2119c00, size=3, set=2)
>       context : nil
>       argNames : instance of SymbolArray (0x2119b40, size=3, set=2)
>       varNames : nil
>       sourceCode : nil
>       ownerClass : class Meta_ServerOptions (0x21113c0)
>       name : Symbol 'prListDevices'
>       primitiveName : Symbol '_ListAudioDevices'
>       filenameSymbol : Symbol '/usr/share/SuperCollider/SCClassLibrary/Common/Control/Server.sc'
>       charPos : Integer 4025
>   }
>   ERROR: Primitive 'none' failed.
>   Failed.
>   RECEIVER:
>      nil
>   CALL STACK:
>       MethodError:reportError   0x35be518
>           arg this = 
>       Nil:handleError   0x1ee0b78
>           arg this = nil
>           arg error = 
>       Thread:handleError   0x3470ab8
>           arg this = 
>           arg error = 
>       Object:throw   0x3636a78
>           arg this = 
>       Object:primitiveFailed   0x3cd86c8
>           arg this = nil
>       Interpreter:interpretPrintCmdLine   0x3d44b98
>           arg this = 
>           var res = nil
>           var func = 
>           var code = "ServerOptions.devices;"
>           var doc = nil
>           var ideClass = 
>       Process:interpretPrintCmdLine   0x37c8708
>           arg this = 
>   ^^ The preceding error dump is for ERROR: Primitive 'none' failed.
>   Failed.
>   RECEIVER: nil

I am new to supercollider and I having a hard time figuring the reason for the error. Please suggest me how to resolve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question. You might do better on SuperUser or a tech specific forum.

Comment: any Stackexchange forum this will fit into? Don't prefer other forums much, this place is much more comfortable :)

Comment: See the answer below. This is a configuration problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: The answer below is not correct, my headphone is configured properly and is in working condition, see my reply to the answer below. It is not a hardware configuration problem for sure. It can be software configuration problem, which can be programmatically done (I am using SuperCollider IDE).

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem (no output from supercollider at all, just complete and total silence), and this post ultimately led me to the right solution. I think it will be helpful to you and others.

From [the ServerOptions documentation](http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/ServerOptions.html#-device), I found that I could configure how SC talks to jack with environment variables.

In my case, I start scsynth with the relevant environment variables like so:

```
  SC_JACK_DEFAULT_INPUTS="system:capture_1" SC_JACK_DEFAULT_OUTPUTS="system" scsynth -u 57110 &
```

It seems this can also be done from within sclang like so:

```
  "SC_JACK_DEFAULT_INPUTS".setenv("system:capture_1");
  "SC_JACK_DEFAULT_OUTPUTS".setenv("system");
```

In your case, where you are connecting to the wrong outputs, you might want to start scsynth like this:

```
   SC_JACK_DEFAULT_OUTPUTS="system:playback_3,system:playback_4" scsynth -u 57110 &
```

Another alternative that will let you play with these connections and find what works for you is to use the jack_lsp, jack_connect, and jack_disconnect commands.

To see all of the ins/outs of your jack server as well as the current connections, run

```
   jack_lsp -c
```

From your post, I think you will see something like

```
system:capture_1
    SuperCollider:in_1
system:capture_2
    SuperCollider:in_2
system:playback_1
    SuperCollider:out_1
system:playback_2
    SuperCollider:out_2
system:playback_3
system:playback_4
SuperCollider:out_1
    system:playback_1
SuperCollider:out_2
    system:playback_2
```

To make SuperCollider output to your headphones and speakers, you could conect out_1 and out_2 to playback_3 and playback_4 (assuming those are your headphones) like so:

```
jack_connect SuperCollider:out_1 system:playback_3
jack_connect SuperCollider:out_2 system:playback_4
```

To disconnect from the speakers, you could do

```
jack_disconnect SuperCollider:out_1 system:playback_1
jack_disconnect SuperCollider:out_2 system:playback_2
```

Run `jack_lsp -c` again to see if your system is setup how you want!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I discovered the solution by using Catia from KXStudio. See [Catia](http://kxstudio.sourceforge.net/Applications:Catia)
Catia is a JACK Patchbay. (Other patchbays are available. QJackctl and Patchage are examples). On my system (Ubuntu 14.04 on a  Dell Studio laptop), SuperCollider maps its first 4 outputs to the 4 system playbacks. The first 2 system playbacks are the speakers, system playbacks 3 and 4 are the headphones. By remapping out1 and out2 from SC to playback_3 and playback_4, I hear it through the headphones. So, get hold of a patchbay for JACK, and see what you see.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling countless times with this issue I managed to get it working with:

1. Add your user to the `audio` linux group.
2. Use `cadence` to start jack

Additional resource that could be helpful: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/JACK_Audio_Connection_Kit

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: the big long error message saying "`A primitive was not bound`" is unpleasant but in this case it just means you typed the wrong command. I don't know where you got that command `ServerOptions.devices` from but it's just wrong. Maybe the message was intended to tell you to type `s.options.device` which is more sensible but it's NOT what you need to do. Forget that and forget that long error message.

Secondly: the message you see when you boot the server is good, it tells you that the server has booted and connected to jack. SuperCollider is happy. If you hear sound out of the speakers but not from the headphones (I take it you mean when you plug the headphones in!), this is NOT a supercollider problem but just a standard operating-system issue about setting the volume on your headphones.

It appears that you're using linux so run the command `alsamixer` in a terminal, that's a good way to check whether the headphone output is muted. Use `man alsamixer` to understand how to use it, if it's not familiar to you.

Comment: Please note I can hear other sounds in the headphone, like when I play music or video but I specifically not able to hear sound from SuperCollider. Also note, ServerOptions.devices and s.options.devices are same.

Comment: NOT `s.options.devices` - it should be `s.options.device`

Comment: I'm afraid it's hard to diagnose further, but I still think the headphones problem is not SuperCollider-specific. To verify this, find another audio software that uses jack and check if that can output to headphones.