# No sound from SuperCollider with Jack2

Tags: linux, audio, jack, supercollider

Note: similar but not the same as [SuperCollider not audible on headphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044345/supercollider-not-audible-on-headphone), because my issue is not restricted to headphones, and the fix for that question (remapping to system:playback_{3,4}) does not apply to my situation

I am trying to use SuperCollider (on linux), but am unable to hear any sound from it. jackdbus is running, and SuperCollider is able to connect to it with no error. Here is the output when I (re-)boot the SuperCollider server

```
booting 57110
JackDriver: client name is 'SuperCollider'
SC_AudioDriver: sample rate = 48000.000000, driver's block size = 1024
JackDriver: connected  system:capture_1 to SuperCollider:in_1
JackDriver: connected  system:capture_2 to SuperCollider:in_2
JackDriver: connected  SuperCollider:out_1 to system:playback_1
JackDriver: connected  SuperCollider:out_2 to system:playback_2
SuperCollider 3 server ready.
JackDriver: max output latency 42.7 ms
Receiving notification messages from server localhost
Shared memory server interface initialized
```

However, when I now play a sound, I continue to see no errors, but I also hear nothing. Playing a sound from the tutorial prints this to the Post window

```
Synth("temp__9" : 1000)
```

At the same time, audio from other applications works fine. Everything is routed through PulseAudio to Jack, as described in "The new new way" here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#PulseAudio_through_JACK

Here is the output of `jack_lsp -c`

```
system:capture_1
   PulseAudio JACK Source:front-left
   SuperCollider:in_1
system:capture_2
   PulseAudio JACK Source:front-right
   SuperCollider:in_2
system:playback_1
   PulseAudio JACK Sink:front-left
   SuperCollider:out_1
system:playback_2
   PulseAudio JACK Sink:front-right
   SuperCollider:out_2
PulseAudio JACK Sink:front-left
   system:playback_1
PulseAudio JACK Sink:front-right
   system:playback_2
PulseAudio JACK Source:front-left
   system:capture_1
PulseAudio JACK Source:front-right
   system:capture_2
SuperCollider:in_1
   system:capture_1
SuperCollider:in_2
   system:capture_2
SuperCollider:in_3
SuperCollider:in_4
SuperCollider:in_5
SuperCollider:in_6
SuperCollider:in_7
SuperCollider:in_8
SuperCollider:out_1
   system:playback_1
SuperCollider:out_2
   system:playback_2
SuperCollider:out_3
SuperCollider:out_4
SuperCollider:out_5
SuperCollider:out_6
SuperCollider:out_7
SuperCollider:out_8
```

How can I find out why I hear nothing from SuperCollider?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and it was fixed by running "qjackctl" from terminal, and in the settings, change the interface:

Screenshot of settings in qjackctl:

[image]

Comment: Can you advise how to make the exact same configuration change but using Cadence instead of qjackctl?

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski I haven't worked with Cadence but found some instructions. In the System tab, click configure, choose tab driver in the popup, and change the interface there. Have a look at the source: [http://libremusicproduction.com/articles/demystifying-jack-–-beginners-guide-getting-started-jack](http://libremusicproduction.com/articles/demystifying-jack-–-beginners-guide-getting-started-jack)

Comment: a belated thank you. Now, what would be the next thing to try if the "Device/Interface" select is empty and disabled, and there is a similar symptom in qjackctl where the "Interface" select says "default" and is also greyed out?