# Supercollider No sound while everything seems to be setup ok

Tags: supercollider

I have a fresh instalation of supercollider 3.10.0. When I run:

```
s.boot;
{ [SinOsc.ar(440, 0, 0.2), SinOsc.ar(442, 0, 0.2)] }.play;
```

I should hear something right? But I hear no sound, while all other sounds apps do have sound. I tried this solution: [No sound from SuperCollider with Jack2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29871614/no-sound-from-supercollider-with-jack2) but it didn't work for me. What can I do to find the problem?

My log says

```
Booting server 'localhost' on address 127.0.0.1:57110.
jackdmp 1.9.12
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2016 Grame.
Copyright 2016-2017 Filipe Coelho.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
configuring for 48000Hz, period = 1024 frames (21.3 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
JackDriver: client name is 'SuperCollider'
SC_AudioDriver: sample rate = 48000.000000, driver's block size = 1024
JackDriver: connected  system:capture_1 to SuperCollider:in_1
JackDriver: connected  system:capture_2 to SuperCollider:in_2
JackDriver: connected  SuperCollider:out_1 to system:playback_1
JackDriver: connected  SuperCollider:out_2 to system:playback_2
SuperCollider 3 server ready.
JackDriver: max output latency 42.7 ms
Requested notification messages from server 'localhost'
localhost: server process's maxLogins (1) matches with my options.
localhost: keeping clientID (0) as confirmed by server process.
Shared memory server interface initialized
-> Synth('temp__0' : 1000)
```

Is there anything suspicious? Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to hear sound from other jack apps?
When you open the graph in qjackctl and boot supercollider, is Supercollider connected to your system output?

Comment: I had an linux xubuntu installation and everything was connected. Now I have installed linux mint and it works out of the box.